# How to model a forum using Amazon DynamoDB without hot-partitions?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

The AWS DynamoDB documentation includes an example [schema for a forum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleTables.html). However, the number of questions this schema is able to answer seems very small. In addition, the table seems to suffer from a hot-key problem (a burst of replies backs up on the same partition).

In a talk title "Advanced Design Patterns for Amazon DynamoDB" the presenter [around 43 minutes breaks down](https://youtu.be/jzeKPKpucS0?t=2559) a complex use-case from Audible using only a single table with 3 GSI (indexes).

I'm trying to learn proper DynamoDB modeling coming from a standard RDBMS 3NF background. How would a forum be designed to prevent hot-partitions while still meeting these common use-cases?

Queries:

- Topics by Forum (sorted by date posted, or most recent reply)
- Replies by Topic (sorted by date posted with pagination)
- Replies by User (sorted by date posted)
- Topics by User (sorted by date posted)
- Topics with most votes

Basic Schema(?):

> - Forum: Partition key: Forum_GUID. Attributes: Name, Desc
> - User: Partition key: User_GUID. Attributes: email, join_date
> - Thread: Composite key: Forum_GUID, Topic_GUID. Attributes: posted_by, date, votes, body, subject
> - Reply: Composite key: Topic_GUID, Reply_GUID. Attributes: posted_by, date, votes, body

I'm assuming there are multiple solutions (including using a single table). I'm looking for any answer that can solve this while providing guidance on when, and how, to [properly use indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes.html) to scale out an application's writes.

Comment: Not every use case is appropriate for DynamoDB.  Some things belong in relational databases.

Comment: To avoid "hot partitions" you can add a random suffix/calculated suffix to your partition key to expand the space. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can use the above schema. Now for you queries

1. Topics by Forum (sorted by date posted, or most recent reply)

   ```
    Select from GSI1 where GSI1 pk=Forum123 and sortby GSI1 SK
   ```

   you can choose whom to keep in GSI1 Sk recent reply/date posted based on which use case is frequently asked.
2. Replies by Topic (sorted by date posted with pagination)

   ```
    Select where pk=topic and sk startswith reply and sortby sk
   ```
3. Replies by User (sorted by date posted)

   ```
    Select from GSI2 where pk=User123 and sk startswith reply and sortby sk
   ```
4. Topics by User (sorted by date posted)

   ```
    Select from GSI2 where pk=User123 and sk startswith topic and sortby sk
   ```
5. Topics with most votes

```
This will require another GSI if you want to do this operation across multiple forums. but This GSI will certainly suffer from hot key issue. since there will be only one key. Instead of doing that, you can keep one fixed key value in your table who keeps these counts. and these values are updated by an async process.
```

Comment: This is a solid start to a forum or blog (a lot of shared design). However, it has a hot-key issue with all replies going to the same topic partition key. So if this was some popular content I would expect users to eventually get blocks. Not really sure any other way to handle this though without something complex and buggy like a scatter-gather design. Maybe a complex write queue between the database to buffer the writes for later.

Comment: what is the scale we are talking about here? if you have time, energy and money can you please do a profiling and see when do we hit a bottleneck?

Comment: (open for discussion and could be wrong) can we really avoid hot keys in this use case?( apart from doing updates asynchronously, which will have its own complexities)

Comment: We would hit a bottleneck when `WCU < replies`. With bursting and auto-scaling this can fudge some. Lets assume the table was provisioned with 50 RCU & WCU. If the page sees a huge response (viral), then with 100 commenters a second, 50 would be blocked and the API call would have to try again. If this continues for several minutes either your web servers will eventually have to stop trying and drop the requests, or store the replies somewhere else for later. AWS SQS is one option, then after the wave passes you could read out replies and try them again.

Comment: try this https://theburningmonk.com/2019/03/understanding-the-scaling-behaviour-of-dynamodb-ondemand-tables/

Comment: theburningmonk link is helpful and shows us that with On-Demand tables, the WCU/RCU's can grow beyond the 4,000 cap given enough time. If there are sudden spikes in throughput however, you will still have throttling and possible lost reads/writes while the table adapts to the new load. When the table shrinks back after the load, I wonder if the 4k limit returns after some amount of time.

Comment: @bestwishes shouldn't 1 be "Select from GSI1 where GSI1 pk=Forum123 and sortby GSI1 SK"?

Comment: I'm curious how this would scale out if we allowed replies on replies on replies, sort of like reddit.  If we have a reply tree 10 deep are we making separate dynamoDB queries for each reply on each reply (etc etc) to build the full message tree on a page so the user can see all replies?