# Amazon SimpleDB & DynamoDB for storing blog posts

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-simpledb

Consider a simple blog post schema has the following columns

```
ID 
Author 
Category 
Status 
CreatedDateTime
UpdatedDateTime
```

So assume the following queries

- query by ID
- query by Author, paginated
- query by (Author, Status), sorted by CreatedDateTime, paginated
- query by (Category, Status), sorted by CreatedDateTime, paginated

So seems without doing much works, SimpleDB would be more easy to implement the codes?

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55340000/how-to-model-a-forum-using-amazon-dynamodb-without-hot-partitions

Answer (score 2):

SimpleDB is barely supported by AWS any more - you can't even find it in the AWS console, so while it may work for you, personally I would be deciding between DynamoDB and DocumentDB (assuming you want NoSQL) - don't think there is any reason to start a new project on such an old offering at this point.

Comment: It's cheap cheap cheap. That's why Amazon stopped promoting it. And it's great for small projects with low performance requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DynamoDB because it has a lot of useful features such as [Point in Time Recovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-continuous-backups-and-point-in-time-recovery-pitr/), [transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-support-for-transactions/), [encryption-at-rest](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/now-available-encryption-at-rest-for-amazon-dynamodb/), and [activity streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) that SimpleDB does not have.

If you're operating on a small scale, DynamoDB has the advantage that it allows you to set a maximum capacity for your table, which means you can make sure you stay in the free tier.

If you're operating at a larger scale, DynamoDB automatically handles all of the partitioning of your data (and has, for all practical purposes, limitless capacity), whereas [SimpleDB has a limit of 10 GB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDBLimits.html) per domain (aka "table") and you are required to manage any horizontal partitioning across domains that you might need.

Finally, there are signs that SimpleDB is already on a deprecation path. For example, if you look at the [SimpleDB release notes](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/?tag=releasenotes%23keywords%23amazon-simpledb), you will see that the last update was in 2011, whereas DynamoDB had several new features announced at the last re:Invent conference. Also, there are a number of reddit posts (such as [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a3280t/no_amazon_simpledb/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8rwov0/whats_wrong_with_simpledb_and_should_i_use_it/), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/2iuw11/cant_find_simpledb/)) where the general consensus is that SimpleDB is already deprecated, and in some of the threads, [Jeff Barr](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/author/jbarr/) even commented and did not contradict any of the assertions that SimpleDB is deprecated.

---

That being said, in DynamoDB, you can support your desired queries. 
You will need two [Global Secondary Indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html), which use a [composite sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html). Your queries can be supported with the following schema:

- `ID` — hash key of your table
- `Author` — hash key of the `Author-Status-CreatedDateTime-index`
- `Category` — hash key of the `Category-Status-CreatedDateTime-index`
- `Status`
- `CreatedDateTime`
- `UpdatedDateTime`
- `Status-CreatedDateTime` — sort key of `Author-Status-CreatedDateTime-index` and `Category-Status-CreatedDateTime-index`. This is a composite attribute that exists to enable some of your queries. It is simply the value of `Status` with a separator character (I'll assume it's `#` for the rest of this answer), and `CreatedDateTime` appended to the end. (Personal opinion here: use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) timestamps instead of unix timestamps. It will make troubleshooting a lot easier.)

Using this schema, you can satisfy all of your queries.

**query by ID:**
Simply perform a [`GetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) request on the main table using the blog post Id.

**query by Author, paginated:**
Perform a [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on the `Author-Status-CreatedDateTime-index` with a key condition expression of `Author = :author`.

**query by (Author, Status), sorted by CreatedDateTime, paginated:** 
Perform a `Query` on the `Author-Status-CreatedDateTime-index` with a key condition expression of `Author = :author and begins_with(Status-CreatedDateTime, :status)`. The results will be returned in order of ascending `CreatedDateTime`.

**query by (Category, Status), sorted by CreatedDateTime, paginated:** 
Perform a `Query` on the `Category-Status-CreatedDateTime-index` with a key condition expression of `Author = :author and begins_with(Status-CreatedDateTime, :status)`. The results will be returned in order of ascending `CreatedDateTime`. (Additionally, if you wanted to get all the blog posts in the "technology" category that have the status `published` and were created in 2019, you could use a key condition expression of `Category = "technology" and begins_with(Status-CreatedDateTime, "published#2019")`.

The sort order of the results can be controlled using the `ScanIndexForward` field of the Query request. The default is `true` (sort ascending); but by setting it to `false` DynamoDB will return results in descending order.

DynamoDB has built in support for paginating the results of a Query operation. Basically, any time that there are more results that were not returned, the query response will contain a `lastEvaluatedKey` which you can pass into your next query request to pick up where you left off. (See [Query Pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination) for more details about how it works.)

---

On the other hand, if you're already familiar with SQL, and you want to make this as easy for yourself as possible, consider just using the [Aurora Serverless Data API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless/).

Comment: This is a good answer. Since the OP hasn't created the table yet, it might be wise to consider [local secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) over global. Also, the `Author-Status-CreatedDate` index might not produce the desired order for the query by just `Author`. Depends on what the OP wants. For that reason, consider setting the range key of the table to just `Author`. In summary, hash key of `ID`, range key of `Author`, and the two secondary indexes that Mathew laid out.

Comment: Range key of Author as @bigh_29 has described will not allow you to query by author. And best practice is to always prefer GSIs over LSIs.

Comment: Gah, you are correct on the range key if `ID` is the partition key. It would only work if all the articles for an author were hashed into the same partition. This kills the idea of using LSIs as well. A different hash key would be needed for either of those ideas to work.